# How do I get a column from an SQLAlchemy result using a column variable?

Tags: sqlalchemy

How can I get at the column of a result if I have a variable for the column?  The below is a simplified example. I have a variable that contains the column I want, which will be used in the query. I now want to get the same column from the result.

```
col_id = some_table.id
query = session.query(col_id)
for row in query:
   id = row ?? col_id
```

I don't want to have to know the name of the column, as the actual code structure is more like this:

```
col_id, query = build_query()
for row in query:
  id = row ?? col_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access it using the `key` attribute of the column.

```py
for row in query:
    id_ = row[col_id.key]
```

but this approach is deprecated and will be removed in SQLAlchemy 2.0.  The recommended approach is to use the row's `_mapping` attribute.

```py
for row in query:
    id_ = row._mapping[id_col.key]
```

or you could output the rows as dictionaries:

```py
for row in query.mappings():
    id_ = row[id_col.key]
```